# How to set JScrollPane Layout to be the same as JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

```
Tabel1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(x,y));
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(Tabel1);
```

When I run the program the scrollpane appears bigger than the table.  How can I make the scrollpane layout the same as the table?

Comment: The size of the scroll pane is defined by the container (and the corresponding layout manager) in which you insert the scroll pane. Consider adding an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your question for better help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `how i can make scrollpane layout the same of table??`

if your `JTable` contains only a  few rows

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

- `Tabel1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(x,y));`

use [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) correctly, then not `Tabel1` but `tabel1`