# Adding Jbutton to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

Need a simple Swing code to demonstrate how to add a button in a column of a Jtable using tablecellrenderer and tablecelleditor.

Comment: Check this topic this may helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321623/adding-button-to-jtable

Comment: need a full sample code..i can't understand it..

Comment: What have you tried? There are many sources available for doing this. Look at this http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/   by Rob Camick. It is explained very well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add button to `JTable`

```
JTable table = new JTable(new JTableModel()); 
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 
        
TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
table.getColumn("Button1").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
table.getColumn("Button2").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
```

Sample `JTableModel`, This is manage the columns and rows, Setting components

```
public static class JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[] {"Id", "Stuff", "Button1", "Button2"};
        private static final Class<?>[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class<?>[] {Integer.class, String.class, JButton.class,  JButton.class};
        
        @Override public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
        }

        @Override public int getRowCount() {
            return 4;
        }
        
        @Override public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex];
        }
        
        @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
            /*Adding components*/
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return rowIndex;
                case 1: return "Text for "+rowIndex;
                case 2: // fall through
               /*Adding button and creating click listener*/
                case 3: final JButton button = new JButton(COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex]);
                        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(button), 
                                        "Button clicked for row "+rowIndex);
                            }
                        });
                        return button;
                default: return "Error";
            }
        }   
    }
```

Sample `Button click listener` , This manage the when mouse is clicked over the component

```
private static class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private final JTable table;
        
        public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX()); // get the coloum of the button
            int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); //get the row of the button

            /*Checking the row or column is valid or not*/
            if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                if (value instanceof JButton) {
                    /*perform a click event*/
                    ((JButton)value).doClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample JTable Cell Renderer, Managing the cell component

```
private static class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {        
        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JButton button = (JButton)value;
            return button;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: button click does not work that way

Comment: you've missed table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));

Comment: smart solution ,,, i like it

Comment: More simple solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440287/341117

Comment: You are putting things that are supposed to be in the View (the JButton) into the Model (TableModel). The JButton should only be part of the renderer. -1.

Answer (score 26):

Here a really nice example which adds a `JButton` to a cell in `JTable`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class JButtonTableExample {

    public JButtonTableExample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButtonTable Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{{"button 1", "foo"},
                    {"button 2", "bar"}}, new Object[]{"Button", "String"});

        JTable table = new JTable(dm);
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));


        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());//thanks mKorbel +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551995/how-to-set-jscrollpane-layout-to-be-the-same-as-jtable

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);//so buttons will fit and not be shown butto..

        frame.add(scroll);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JButtonTableExample();
            }
        });

    }
}

class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    public ButtonRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    protected JButton button;
    private String label;
    private boolean isPushed;

    public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
        super(checkBox);
        button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        button.setText(label);
        isPushed = true;
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        if (isPushed) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
        }
        isPushed = false;
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        isPushed = false;
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }
}
```

**References:**

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm

Comment: How to addActionlistener for that Button to delete the corresponding row..

Comment: See http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/

Comment: I tried this code and it displays button perfecly, but I am not able to click it, its not enabled or disabled, so do you know what is the issue with it? It looks like on the picture you posted, but i cant click it...Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fixed the issue. Remember that cell must be Editable. So in your cell editor you need to have something like this:                   
`@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e){
    return true;
}` Hope this will help someone!