# jButton not clickable in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I got the problem, that I cannot click on buttons. They behave like they are just textfields with the design of buttons.

my `Main`:

```
    tableModStudents = (DefaultTableModel) studentsTable.getModel();
    studentsTable.getColumn(studentsTable.getColumnName(8))
                 .setCellRenderer(new JButtonRenderer());
    studentsTable.getColumn(studentsTable.getColumnName(8))
                 .setCellEditor(new JButtonEditor());
```

my `CellRenderer`:

```
public class JButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {    
    private JButton button = new JButton();

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object buttonText, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
            int row, int column) {
        table.setShowGrid(true);
        button.setText("Details");
        button.setToolTipText(buttonText.toString());
        return button;
    }
}
```

my `CellEditor`:

```
    public class JButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private JButton button;
    private String txt;

    public JButtonEditor() {
        super();
        button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("Button gedrückt!");
            }
        });
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    public void cancelCellEditing() {
    }

    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        txt = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        button.setText(txt);
        return button;
    }
}
```

Can you find the issue with that? It drives my crazy...

Thanks so much :)

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1475543/243373) on SO has some links to solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

It combines a button renderer and editor in a single class.

All you need to do is provide the custom `Action` to be invoked when you invoke the button (either by clicking on it or by invoking its mnemonic).

Comment: Perfect! Bravo, Easy