# How to add button in row of table

Tags: java, swing

I have table which populated from database. How can i add a single button in last column?

Here is the code for jtable,

```
private void getData(){
        try{
            con = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB();
            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql  = "SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE status = 0";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: learn this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833688/adding-jbutton-to-jtable) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Concentrate on one question at a time:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122112/get-all-data-from-database-in-textfield-when-jlist-item-selected. You still haven't asked a reasonable question in your last posting. Either update the question or delete it so people don't waste time trying to understand what you are asking. And post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start with simple example that would add the button into JTable cell. Later you can setModel() with resultset from database.

An [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) would demonstrate how to add JButton into JTable Cell.

```
public class JButtonTableExample {

public JButtonTableExample() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButtonTable Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] {
        {
            "button 1",
            "foo"
        }, {
            "button 2",
            "bar"
        }
    }, new Object[] {
        "Button",
        "String"
    });

    JTable table = new JTable(dm);
    table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
    table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));


    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
    frame.add(scroll);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JButtonTableExample();
        }
    });

 }
}


class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }
 }

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

protected JButton button;
private String label;
private boolean isPushed;

public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fireEditingStopped();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    return button;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
    }
    isPushed = false;
    return label;
}

@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
 }
}
```